# What is the end of life for .NET 4.6.1 higher versions in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: .net, eol

There is a confusion regarding EOL for .NET FW higher than 4.6.1.
I am running an application which is based on 4.6.2 in Window Server 2012.
We are planning to upgrade our servers to Window Server 2022.

As per the below link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework?source=docs

The EOL is on Jan 12, 2027.

Whereas the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework says it follow the life cycle policy of Parent OS ?

It means, if I go with the second link I am getting an understanding that its EOL is Oct, 2023 which is the EOL for Windows server 2012.

I need some brief explanation on it to clear my understanding.

Comment: There is only ever a single version of .NET 4+ installed, and that depends on Windows updates, which you won't get beyond Oct 2023 for 2012r2

Comment: Have you tried updating the application to 4.8.1 to make sure there are no changes which will break it?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Server 2022 comes with .NET Framework [4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-48), you can't uninstall nor downgrade it, so the EOL of 4.6.2 doesn't apply when you migrate to Windows Server 2022 because your app no longer runs on 4.6.2 but 4.8 (or more likely 4.8.1 if you allow it to update). The EOL instead becomes Oct 14, 2031, following Windows Server 2022 EOL.